# Moving a HDD from one PC to another

Tags: windows, hard-drive, operating-systems

I want to install my old desktop's HDD, which has Windows 7 installed in it to my new desktop that has a SSD with Windows 10. I just want to copy some games and files and then I would definetly format it.

If i just plug it in the new motherboard, will I face problems booting? 
If so what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If i just plug it in the new motherboard, will I face problems booting?

This depends. Motherboards provide a menu for the *Boot order*. So if your system does not start properly after plugging in the old HDD, look for a method to change the boot order (to ignore the HDD and not boot from it). Usually you have to press <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>DEL</kbd> or during the boot process.

Mastering that challenge, your new system should boot and mount the *old HDD* (otherwise, look for a way to manually mount it). Then you can copy the old files and everything should be *fine*.

Unfortunately copying programs/games isn't successful all the time because the programs/games store information in the *Windows Registry*. These information are hard to replicate. So most of the time it is easier to do a fresh install and only copy the saved games/data.

Comment: Some computers use F2 or Del to get into the bios / setup. Watch carefully for any messages that show during the first boot screen.

Comment: @R-D: Thank you for providing additional key combinations so that the answer gets more complete.

Comment: thank you, it simply worked without the need to change the boot order.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to temporarily boot to the old drive, you shouldn't ordinarily face problems booting, so long as the HDD isn't IDE and your motherboard only has sata. I would recommend booting to the SSD, then connecting your HDD through an adapter and then copying the files over that way.